# Jquery Mobile Gesture Swipe left/right issue in android phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, swipe-gesture

I am trying to achieve left/right swipe in jquery mobile/phonegap in android. I have sample code, but when i swipe, nothing occurs on it.

Here is my javascript code

```
$("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
});
```

Here is body content

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
            <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
        </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
            <li><a href="#home">Back to the Home Page</a></li>
        </ul>

        <p>
            Yeah!<br />You Swiped Right to view Page 1
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements and **they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call**. The document element is available in the **head of the document** before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Furthermore as mentioned in the [jQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) you can bind to these events like you would with other jQuery events, using live() or bind().

You may check the following examples:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Swipe</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#listitem').live("swiperight", function(){
                $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                        <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
                    <li><a href="#home">Back to the Home Page</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p>
                    Yeah!<br />You Swiped Right to view Page 1
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Swipe Example</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("swiperight", "#listitem", function() {
                $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                        <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
                    <li><a href="#home">Back to the Home Page</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p>
                    Yeah!<br />You Swiped Right to view Page 1
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example 3:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Swipe Example</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                        <li id="listitem">Swipe Right to view Page 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
                    <li><a href="#home">Back to the Home Page</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p>
                    Yeah!<br />You Swiped Right to view Page 1
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
                $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Tolis,I have one problem regarding swiping. I am using phonegap/jquery mobile on android. I have used your code, but it is not responsive, I have to swipe it 3-4 times to get the swipe event working.do you have any idea about it?